# How to extract origin domain name in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have following sample data in my `webpage` column:

```
ID     webpage

1  |   http://google.com
2  |   https://www.google.com/
3  |   https://inbox.google.com
4  |   https://google.com/
```

I now want to add new column `origin` which contains only domain name (google.com).

1. How can I extract the origin from from such data?
2. How can I add these extracted values as a new column `origin` into my table?

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of sub domains that may come in your column?

Comment: No I don't know ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to get host name. See [Regular Expressions Cookbook, 2nd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch08s10.html).

For example:

```
WITH urls AS (
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY['http://google.com', 'https://www.google.com/', 'https://inbox.google.com', 'https://google.com/']::text[]) AS url
)
SELECT (regexp_matches(url, '^[a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*://([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&''\(\)*+,;=]+@)?([a-z0-9\-._~%]+|\[[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&''\(\)*+,;=:]+\])', 'g'))[2]
FROM urls;
```

You'll get:

```
google.com
www.google.com
inbox.google.com
google.com
```

---

To put the extracted host into new column you can use `DEFAULT` value to be calculated from existing `webpage` column, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE _table_name_ ADD COLUMN origin text DEFAULT get_host_name(webpage);
```

Comment: But i only want get google.com, evertytime without subdomain

Comment: You could split the host into parts on `.` and take only two last parts to get `google.com`. But what about `https://www.amazon.co.uk/`? You would need three last parts to get `amazon.co.uk`. So it is hard to define what you really need...

Comment: Splitting by ´.´ will also not help. Maybe I should write a small script for that. The problem is that I have about 300M records..

Answer (score 1):

For the sample data provided above you can get the required output using [a "non-capturing" set of parentheses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE)

```
SELECT ID,
       website,
      substring(website from '(?:.*://)?(?:www\.)?(?:inbox\.)?([^/]*)') AS origin
from tb1;
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b3ecf678b9d4b6dbdfaf7b3e7d56773b)

*OUTPUT*

[image]

Comment: google was only a sample, I have thausend of different subdomains